# Windows allow user to run commands

Tags: php, windows, system-administration

On windows xp I can run many commands form PHP with shell_exec() function.

I need to use [OfficeToPDF](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF/releases) on windows 10 with PHP.
My php script is:

```
<?php
$command = 'OfficeToPDF input.docx output.pdf';
$exec = shell_exec($command);
echo $exec;
?>
```

This script works on windows XP Professional, but not on windows 7, 8, 10.
OfficeToPdf simply opens Microsoft Word and saves file as PDF.
What changed on win7, win8, win10? Why I couldn't execute this command from PHP on new OS's?

I have apache service automaticly starts from SYSTEM user.

**UPDATE:** But I can run `OfficeToPDF input.docx output.pdf` command when I open cmd window manually.

Comment: _"This script works on windows XP Professional, but not on windows 7, 8, 10"_ - read [ask] and explain what it does or doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that some environment variables are missing that are required. You should try running from within a command window instance, that will setup the default env vars:

```
    $command = 'cmd /c OfficeToPDF input.docx output.pdf';
    $exec = shell_exec($command);
    echo $exec;
```

You might want to use the full path to OfficeToPDF, input.docx and output.pdf in case your default directory is incorrect, or call chdir() first.

The meaning of /C is:

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

Comment: I also used fullpath. Additionally I also added OfficeToPDF to PATH. And your code don't worked on me. Winword opened and started to eat ram. But not converted. After I terminated windord.exe from task manager, I got this error on php: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Did not convert....
Basicly I am not getting any errors on windows xp or if I manually run command